# Jetpack compose bottomsheet animation

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I'm trying to animate BottomSheet corner radius relatively to a fraction. The problem is that it has progress 1 by default in the beginning and in the end if reach end and still dragging. So how i can fix this issue?

Here's progress updates:

```
D/SHEET: progress: 1.0 isExpanded: false
D/SHEET: progress: 1.0 isExpanded: false
D/SHEET: progress: 0.16564026 isExpanded: false
D/SHEET: progress: 0.30916774 isExpanded: false

D/SHEET: progress: 0.44451225 isExpanded: false
D/SHEET: progress: 0.5586605 isExpanded: false
D/SHEET: progress: 0.65918773 isExpanded: false
D/SHEET: progress: 0.7307293 isExpanded: false
D/SHEET: progress: 0.80399936 isExpanded: false
D/SHEET: progress: 0.84945077 isExpanded: false
D/SHEET: progress: 0.8997049 isExpanded: false
D/SHEET: progress: 0.9339056 isExpanded: false
D/SHEET: progress: 0.9522736 isExpanded: false
D/SHEET: progress: 0.9697125 isExpanded: false
D/SHEET: progress: 0.9797893 isExpanded: false
D/SHEET: progress: 0.99829936 isExpanded: false
D/SHEET: progress: 0.9998195 isExpanded: false
D/SHEET: progress: 0.9999819 isExpanded: false
D/SHEET: progress: 1.0 isExpanded: false
D/SHEET: progress: 1.0 isExpanded: true
```

Code i've tried:

```
val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
    bottomSheetState = 
rememberBottomSheetState(BottomSheetValue.Collapsed)
  )

 val radius =
    if (bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.progress == 1f && 
bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.isCollapsed) 30.dp
    else (30 * (1f - 
bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.progress)).dp

BottomSheetScaffold(
    scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
    sheetContent = {
        SheetContent(tracks)
    },

    sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(
        bottomStart = 0.dp,
        bottomEnd = 0.dp,
        topStart = radius,
        topEnd = radius
    ),
    sheetElevation = 8.dp,
    sheetPeekHeight = 400.dp,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()


) {
    MainSheetContent(album)
}
```

Comment: What do you wanna achieve? and can you share your code?

Comment: Something like [that](https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-animate-bottomsheet-content-using-jetpack-compose-3eab972b3bdc) in last example but make corners with right angles in expanded form. But it doesn't have such property like in the link so i cannot understand how can i do it in good way. Code just uses bottomsheet progress to calculate current angle of bottom sheet and because of two one's in progress i can't determine how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after many hours i've found solution for this animation problem.
I did with calculating bottomSheetHeight using this(screenheight u can get through configuration):

```
val bottomSheetHeight = screenHeight - sheetState.bottomSheetState.requireOffset().roundToInt().dp
val fraction = (bottomSheetHeight.value / screenHeight.value + 0.37f) * 0.73f
```

P.s. fraction must be in 0..1 and using log i determine that fraction was in range -0.37..1 so using some math manipulation we get wanted range.

Hope it helps someone :)